# Python check if next element exist in list

Tags: python

I'm doing some challenges with Python.

I have the following code:

```
def SimpleSymbols(str):
    letters = []
    results = []

    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] != '=' and str[i] != '+':
            letters.append(str[i])

            if str[i-1] == '+' and str[i+1] == '+':
                results.append(str[i])

    return len(letters) == len(results)
```

https://repl.it/BH1s/1

If I check for `print(SimpleSymbols('++d+===+c++=='))` everything goes well but if I check for `print(SimpleSymbols('++d+===+c++==+a'))`

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 15, in
>      File "python", line 9, in SimpleSymbols IndexError: string
>   index out of range

Can someone explain me please why?

Comment: Usually in Python functions are `lower_case`, i.e. `simple_symbols`, and you don't redefine builtins like `str` which constructs a string object. Maybe `def simple_symbols(symbols):`. See [PEP8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: Your code returns `True` for `SimpleSymbols("c++")`. Is it intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you get  to the last character of str and it is a letter, then `str[i+1]` does not exist.

You need to place the condition in a `try except` block to avoid this to happen. (You will have to decide what to do in the `except` when an `IndexError` is raised)

```
def SimpleSymbols(str):
    letters = []
    results = []

    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] != '=' and str[i] != '+':
            letters.append(str[i])
        try:
            if str[i-1] == '+' and str[i+1] == '+':
                results.append(str[i])
        except IndexError:
            do what needs to be done in this case.

    return len(letters) == len(results)
```

Comment: I don't think this is an exceptional condition. It can be accounted for with logic. I know [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), but if there were other `IndexError`s it would be difficult to determine what to do.

Comment: Agreed, that's a choice to make on how to handle it. Here, a try except has the advantage of being simpler than changing the logic.

Comment: @PeterWood it is exceptional since more than 95% of the time you won't need to bother and will ne able to `str[i+1]` just fine

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access index `str[i+1]` which is, on the last iteration, out of bounds...

In case you *have to* use it, restrict the loop to run only up to `len(str)-1`. To handle the case: `'++d+===+c++==+a'` you can add a check *after* the loop to verify that the one-before-last element is not `+` (or to add it to the `if` condition in the loop).

Further, it is a bad practice to name your variable `str` which is a python built-in function!

Comment: if i do len-1 then SimpleSymbols('++d+===+c++==+a') is true, which is false in my case, because a isint have the next element a +

Comment: In that case modify: `if str[i-1] == '+' and str[i+1] == '+':` to: `if str[i-1] == '+' and i < len(str)-2 and str[i+1] == '+':`

Answer (score 1):

```
def SimpleSymbols(str):
    letters = []
    results = []

    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] != '=' and str[i] != '+':
            letters.append(str[i])

            if i < len(str)-1 and str[i-1] == '+' and str[i+1] == '+':
                results.append(str[i])

    return len(letters) == len(results)

print SimpleSymbols("=+b+a")
```

writing your code in this way,
everything will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be looking for symbols that are neither `+` nor `=` and check that all such symbols are both followed and preceded by `+`.

The first and last symbol are special cases in that their are either not preceded nor followed by anything and thus, if they are neither `+` nor `=` your function should return `False`.

Since, in python, `some_string[-1]` returns the last character of the string, your loop doesn't break if the first character is neither a `+` nor a `=`. Even returning `True` for input such as `c++`. For the last character, however, your code raise an `IndexError` which is expected.

You can either:

- check if the first or last symbol are in `('+', '=')` and return `False` if they do since they can't be preceded or followed by `+`. Then you can run your loop on the inner string:

  ```
  def SimpleSymbols(symbols):
      control = ('+', '=')

      if symbols[0] not in control or symbols[-1] not in control:
          return False

      for last_index, symbol in enumerate(symbols[1:-1]):
          next_index = last_index + 2
          if letter not in control:
              if symbols[last_index] != '+' or symbols[next_index] != '+':
                  # Found a letter that is not enclosed in two '+'
                  return False
      return True
  ```
- use regular expressions to count the occurences of both the symbols that are not in `('+', '=')` and those in the same group that are enclosed within two `+`:

  ```
  import re

  def SimpleSymbols(symbols):
      simples = len(re.findall(r'[^+=]', symbols))
      enclosed = len(re.findall(r'\+[^+=]\+', symbols))

      return simples == enclosed
  ```